# Allow only one updater to customer in SQL Server 2008

Tags: .net, sql-server-2008

I've done some searching, but haven't found exactly the answer to what I feel must be a common situation, and should have a "best practice" pattern solution:

I have an application written in .NET 4 (C#) with a SQL SERVER 2008 back end.  I have complete control, and there are no outside processes or applications to worry about.

Essentially, I want to do the following:

Allow anybody to see customers and their orders (returned from a main search form).

As soon as a user adds a new order or picks an order to look at or edit, a lock is placed on the entire customer.  Other users will then be able to "read-only" the customer and any orders.

When the user exits the order, the lock is removed (by exiting the screen or by logging out of the app).  Also, and this may be the hard part, the lock is removed if the user crashes (perhaps locks only have a finite time to ensure this?).

I saw application locks, and transactions, but I don't know which to use, they each seem to have their problems.

So what is the best practice for locking a customer, and what is the way for other users to know that the customer is locked by another user?

Answer (score 1):

A manually way to do this is adding two columns in your table: boolean LOCKED and DateTime LAST_LOCKED, and update when a user lock and release when unlocked (update the LAST_LOCKED periodically), put an expiration limit in your application, like 10 minutes, and if the registry is locked more than 10 minutes, unlock then.

Comment: This is exactly how movie / theatre / airline websites work with time based "locks" or "reservations"

Comment: I was looking for a "Lock Record", "Unlock Record" and "Is Record Locked?" commands built into SQL Server.  But I suspected there is no such thing.  Next best is the manual method, and improve it by setting a timer on the user that obtains the lock, he has to update the last-locked-time every 30 seconds.  Then it would be totally safe for the application to expire any locks older than 1 minute.

Answer (score 0):

You right- application lock would be hard to manage and transactional lock has to be as short as possible. 
The idea about "Locked" and "Last_Locked" columns is great. Would also add filtered index for datetime of locked records to speed up unlocking when its necessary and for finding locked customers.